# Nginx can't serve more than 40 contemporary users

Tags: performance, nginx, timeout

I'm testing my Nginx web server (configured with CentminMod) with https://www.blitz.io/ and the server returns timeouts when the connected users are about 40.

I can't understand why! It's Nginx, not Apache!
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on **Server Fault**.

Comment: And don't forget to include full nginx config and mention what's behind nginx

Comment: Asked here thanks! http://serverfault.com/questions/632626/nginx-cant-serve-more-than-40-contemporary-users